# yii2 как передать во вью из контроллера переменную которая может быть null

Tags: php, yii2

При рендеринге вида возникает ошибка `Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null`. Контроллер:

```
        $modelFile = $this->findFileModel($id);

    return $this->render('update', [
        'id' => $id,
        'model' => $form,
        'candidate' => $candidate,
        'modelFileWidget'=> new \frontend\models\UploadForm(),
        'modelFile' => $modelFile,
        'cities'=> ArrayHelper::map($this->cityService->getAll(),'id','name'),
        'skills'=> ArrayHelper::map($this->skillService->getAll(),'id','name'),
    ]);
```

Функция которая находит модель по заданному id:

```
    private function findFileModel($id)
{
    return \common\models\File::find()->where('entity_id = :entity_id', ['entity_id' => $id])->one();
}
```

Функция может возвращать null.Как в этом случае передать переменную $modelFile в метод render? Спасибо.

Comment: А что Вы собираетесь выводить при значении `null`?

Comment: Я хотел бы в первую очередь избавиться от ошибки и  сделал так - `$modelFile = isset($modelFile) ? $modelFile: new \common\models\File();`Но незнааю насколько это правильно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если хочется обрабатывать наличие обновляемого объекта, то нормальное решение.
а стандартный вариант выглядит так:

```
/**
 * Updates an existing Theme model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}



/**
 * Finds the Theme model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return Theme the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Theme::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
}
```

Если нет объекта то вываливается стандартная ошибка. Или можно сделать редирект.
Если выдать ошибку не вариант. можно передать пустую модель

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = ModelClass::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    }
    return new ModelClass();
}
```

Comment: Добрый день!Проблема в том - что модель - это прикрепленный к кандидату файл - и при такой обработке ошибок - как вы написали - при обращении к кандидатам у которых нет прикрепленного файла (например форма редактирования кандидата) - получаем ошибку 404. А она должна открываться вне зависимости от того - есть ли у кандидата файл - или нет.